# Unable to instantiate application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, android, ubuntu-16.04

The issue occurs if:

- I run app from Android Studio , the app runs properly

  then I delete the app and tried to install debug.apk from `.../app/build/outputs/apk/debug.apk`

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04, oracle jdk

but on Windows 7 all works properly(apk can be installed from `.../app/build/outputs/apk/debug.apk` and runs properly)

This error occurs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example, PID: 21084
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.MyApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.MyApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:676)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6289)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.MyApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1004)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:666)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6289) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.MyApp
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

My gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    jackOptions {
        enabled false
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
    jumboMode = true
    preDexLibraries = false
}

signingConfigs {
    //release
    release {
        storeFile file("/keys/apk_key.jks")
        storePassword "apk_key"
        keyAlias "apk_key"
        keyPassword "apk_key"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        debuggable false
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        debuggable true
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "3G"
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

Also I tried to:

- `Invalidate Cache/Restart`
- `Clean Project`
- `Rebuild project`

Comment: rebuild application.

Comment: try to unchecked instant run

Comment: you are using oracle jdk or open jdk?

Comment: @DileepPatel thanks, resolved, I hate this Instant Run!!

Comment: @Nick Unuchek Hi sir,How you solved this problem....I tried below solution it's not working for me please help me.....version 5.0,6.0 it's working....Kitkat version 4.4 it's not working

Comment: @Mariyappan It's another question,...is your minSdkVersion 19 in ...app/build.gradle ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you @Dileep Patel
I faced the same issue. App only worked if it's installed from Android Studio and crashed if it's installed by adb command. Invalidate caches/Restart and disabling Instant Run(Android Studio->Preferences->Instant Run, uncheck "Enable Instance Run") worked in my case.

Answer (score 4):

add multidex in app level gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

enable multidex

```
 defaultConfig {
 multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Last add this code inside application class

```
 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Comment: MultiDex.install(this) did the trick. There is a good explanation on https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html how to enable Multidex for your Android project. Instead of overriding #attachBaseContext() in your Application-Context I would prefer extending from MultiDexApplication instead of Application. MultiDexApplication already overrides #attachBaseContext() with a call of MultiDex.install(this)

Answer (score 1):

I just wanna say that I know this is really dumb and I know the question has already been answered but I changed the name of my App class and forgot to change it in the manifest, for some reason the app still built. Anyway make sure you have the correct name of your app class in the manifests of your project:

```
    <application
    android:name=".CorrectAppClassHere"
        //...
```

Comment: Not dumb, most likely the reason.  If you have an error in your name attribute for the Application or it is missing, the app will still compile!  The exception says the classloader cannot find the class.  Either it is not present, or the name is wrong. This happened to me with Instant Run already disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to gradle helped me

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a test device above API level 20,  you can change your minSdkVersion to 21, instead of adding multidex because API level 20 and above have multidex in it

Answer (score 0):

i have earlier tried a solution to solve a problem with appname in manifest so i added this line  manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "com.tech.turitos" in the app gradle, neither it fixed my issue nor i remembered to remove it so it created this error as soon as i removed it, the app worked properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
<application
            android:name=".App"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

In your *manifest* file just change `allowBackup` to **false**.
Then run the app, you will get an exception.
Then change it back to **true**, this fixes it completely.